# How can I rebuild precompiled headers in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers, build-error

It was needed because I deleted my .idb file and the error message told me to rebuild the precompiled headers.

Comment: It would be better if you supplied complete error message here as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precompiled header produce `.pdb` file, while according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3awe4781.aspx) `.idb` file is:

> The state file, containing dependency information between source files and class definitions, which can be used by the compiler during minimal rebuild and incremental compilation. Use the /Fd compiler option to specify the name of the .idb file. See /Gm (Enable Minimal Rebuild) for more information.

To rebuild a project you can go to `Main menu` -> `Build` -> `Rebuild`. To rebuild just precompiled header you can open context menu in `Solution Explorer` for precompiled header `.cpp` file and chose `Compile` item.

Answer (score 0):

If the precompiled header file is generated at runtime, something like

```
$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pch
```

One additional method is to:

1. Locate the .pch file in the output folder.
2. Delete it.
3. Do a regular build on the project.

This could be attractive when there are build dependencies and you don't want to wait for all of the projects to rebuild.